# How do I make redstone activate when in a bed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building a map but I need to know the simple command on how to make redstone activate after you wake up after sleeping in a bed/when you sleep in a bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a player is sleeping in a bed, they get `Sleeping:1b` in their NBT. You can thus test if someone is sleeping like this:

```
/testfor @a {Sleeping:1b}
```

If you put that in a command block on <kbd>Repeat</kbd> and <kbd>Always Active</kbd>, it will constantly activate, and you can get a redstone signal out of it when it succeeds by using a comparator:

[image: Comparator setup]

Comment: Is this available in 1.8 with a repeating thingy?

Comment: @Player No, that is till 1.9. You need to use Redstone clock in earlier versions. Or update.

Comment: @Player The repeating and chain command blocks were only introduced in 1.9, but you should be able to use another kind of clock, so long as the command block is repeatedly activated.

Comment: @colorfusion, is there a way so that when you wake up you aren't teleported back to the bed, and wake up in the area your teleported to?